# Android Emulator black screen on Fedora /w NVIDIA GPU

Tags: android, android-studio, nvidia, fedora, android-virtual-device

When I try to run an Android emulator (either from Android studio or from command line) I get a black screen.

The common suggestions that I found and tried are:

- Install proprietary drivers (done)
- Set emulated performance graphics to `Hardware - GLES 2.0` (done; results in black screen)
- Set emulated performance graphics to `Software - GLES 2.0` (done; crashes after a few seconds)
- `Wipe data` and start with `Cold boot now` (done; no change)
- try running it from command line (done; but I have no idea what to look for)

  - `emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_31` (with software GLES set in android-studio)

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.9.0 (build_id 8316981) (CL:N/A)
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
INFO    | Info: Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway. ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.9.0 (build_id 8316981) (CL:N/A)
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
INFO    | Info: Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway. ((null):0, (null))

Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
WARNING | cannot add library /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
INFO    | added library /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
INFO    | Sending adb public key [public key]
INFO    | Rootcanal has  been activated.
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_290367.ini
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

- `emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_31 -gpu host` (ends with black screen)

```
# Starts the same as above

Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
WARNING | cannot add library /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
INFO    | added library /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
INFO    | Sending adb public key [public key]
INFO    | Rootcanal has  been activated.
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_290964.ini
```

- `emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_31 -gpu swiftshader_indirect` (crashes)

```
# Starts the same as above

Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
WARNING | cannot add library /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
INFO    | added library /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
INFO    | Sending adb public key [public key]
INFO    | Rootcanal has  been activated.
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_291507.ini
WARNING | change of renderer detected.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

- `./emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_31 -gpu guest` (crashes)

```
# Starts the same as above

Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
WARNING | Your AVD has been configured with an in-guest renderer, but the system image does not support guest rendering.Falling back to 'swiftshader_indirect' mode.
WARNING | cannot add library /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
INFO    | added library /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
INFO    | Sending adb public key [public key]
INFO    | Rootcanal has  been activated.
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_292009.ini
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

- there were also weird tips like move/rename `~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libc++.so` which didn't work

PC stats:

```sh
$ egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
24

$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        4,0M     0  4,0M   0% /dev
tmpfs            32G   87M   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            13G  2,6M   13G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3  931G   35G  895G   4% /
tmpfs            32G   25M   32G   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p3  931G   35G  895G   4% /projects
/dev/nvme0n1p2  520M  257M  255M  51% /boot
/dev/sda1       466G   37G  429G   8% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p1  519M   14M  506M   3% /boot/efi

$ ls -l /dev/kvm 
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root kvm 10, 232 20. dub 22.11 /dev/kvm

$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62Gi        30Gi       3,1Gi       974Mi        29Gi        30Gi
Swap:          8,0Gi        25Mi       8,0Gi


# lshw -class video | grep driver=
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

And `Android Studio 2021.1.1 Patch 3`

What I think is the problem: Something with the GPU. What exactly? I have no idea.

I also tried all with the `-verbose` flag. Here's the verbose one with the black screen:

```
./emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_31 -gpu host -verbose
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.9.0 (build_id 8316981) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found AVD name 'Pixel_XL_API_31'
INFO    | Found AVD target architecture: x86_64
INFO    | argv[0]: './emulator'; program directory: '/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator'
VERBOSE |  Found directory: /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64/
INFO    | emuDirName: '/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator'
INFO    | try dir /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator
INFO    | Trying emulator path '/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64'
INFO    | Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
INFO    | Adding library search path: '/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64'
INFO    | Adding library search path: '/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
INFO    | Adding library search path: '/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++'
VERBOSE | Adding library search path for Qt: '/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib'
VERBOSE | Silencing all qWarning(); use qCWarning(...) instead: QT_LOGGING_RULES=default.warning=false
VERBOSE | Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins
VERBOSE | Setting Qt to use software OpenGL: QT_OPENGL=software
VERBOSE | Setting QML to use software QtQuick2D: QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext
VERBOSE | Overriding pre-existing bad Qt high dpi settings...
VERBOSE | Setting LD_PRELOAD to /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libfreetype.so.6
VERBOSE | emulator: Running :/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[00] = "/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[01] = "-avd"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[02] = "Pixel_XL_API_31"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[03] = "-gpu"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[04] = "host"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[05] = "-verbose"
VERBOSE | Concatenated backend parameters:  /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -avd Pixel_XL_API_31 -gpu host -verbose
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -skin 1440x2560
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -skindir (null)
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -kernel /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//kernel-ranchu
VERBOSE | Target arch = 'x86_64'
VERBOSE | Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
VERBOSE | Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -ramdisk /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//ramdisk.img
VERBOSE | Using initial system image: /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//system.img
VERBOSE | Using initial vendor image: /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//vendor.img
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -data /home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/userdata-qemu.img
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -initdata /home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/userdata.img
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -cache /home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/cache.img
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -sdcard /home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/sdcard.img
VERBOSE | Increasing RAM size to 2048MB
VERBOSE | VM heap size 384MB is below hardware specified minimum of 512MB,setting it to that value
VERBOSE | System image is read only
VERBOSE | Found 1 DNS servers:
VERBOSE |   127.0.0.53
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
VERBOSE | Unexpected feature list:
VERBOSE | Vulkan
VERBOSE | found magic skin width=1440 height=2560 bpp=16

VERBOSE | CPU Acceleration: working
VERBOSE | CPU Acceleration status: KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
VERBOSE | handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
VERBOSE | Bluetooth requested by guest
VERBOSE | started modem simulator host server at port: 38761
INFO    | Info: Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway. ((null):0, (null))

Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
VERBOSE | GPU emulation enabled using 'host' mode
VERBOSE | Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
VERBOSE | create display 0
VERBOSE | setDisplayPose 0 x 0 y 0 w 1440 h 2560 dpi 0
WARNING | cannot add library /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
INFO    | added library /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
INFO    | Sending adb public key [public key]
VERBOSE | Found 1 DNS servers:
VERBOSE |   127.0.0.53
INFO    | Content of hardware configuration file:
INFO    |   hw.cpu.arch = x86_64
INFO    |   hw.cpu.ncore = 4
INFO    |   hw.ramSize = 2048
INFO    |   hw.screen = multi-touch
INFO    |   hw.mainKeys = false
INFO    |   hw.trackBall = false
INFO    |   hw.keyboard = true
INFO    |   hw.keyboard.lid = false
INFO    |   hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
INFO    |   hw.dPad = false
INFO    |   hw.rotaryInput = false
INFO    |   hw.gsmModem = true
INFO    |   hw.gps = true
INFO    |   hw.battery = true
INFO    |   hw.accelerometer = true
INFO    |   hw.gyroscope = true
INFO    |   hw.audioInput = true
INFO    |   hw.audioOutput = true
INFO    |   hw.sdCard = true
INFO    |   hw.sdCard.path = /home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/sdcard.img
INFO    |   disk.cachePartition = true
INFO    |   disk.cachePartition.path = /home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/cache.img
INFO    |   disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
INFO    |   test.quitAfterBootTimeOut = -1
INFO    |   test.delayAdbTillBootComplete = 0
INFO    |   test.monitorAdb = 0
INFO    |   hw.lcd.width = 1440
INFO    |   hw.lcd.height = 2560
INFO    |   hw.lcd.depth = 16
INFO    |   hw.lcd.density = 560
INFO    |   hw.lcd.backlight = true
INFO    |   hw.lcd.vsync = 60
INFO    |   hw.gltransport = pipe
INFO    |   hw.gltransport.asg.writeBufferSize = 1048576
INFO    |   hw.gltransport.asg.writeStepSize = 4096
INFO    |   hw.gltransport.asg.dataRingSize = 32768
INFO    |   hw.gltransport.drawFlushInterval = 800
INFO    |   hw.displayRegion.0.1.xOffset = -1
INFO    |   hw.displayRegion.0.1.yOffset = -1
INFO    |   hw.displayRegion.0.1.width = 0
INFO    |   hw.displayRegion.0.1.height = 0
INFO    |   hw.displayRegion.0.2.xOffset = -1
INFO    |   hw.displayRegion.0.2.yOffset = -1
INFO    |   hw.displayRegion.0.2.width = 0
INFO    |   hw.displayRegion.0.2.height = 0
INFO    |   hw.displayRegion.0.3.xOffset = -1
INFO    |   hw.displayRegion.0.3.yOffset = -1
INFO    |   hw.displayRegion.0.3.width = 0
INFO    |   hw.displayRegion.0.3.height = 0
INFO    |   hw.display1.width = 0
INFO    |   hw.display1.height = 0
INFO    |   hw.display1.density = 0
INFO    |   hw.display1.xOffset = -1
INFO    |   hw.display1.yOffset = -1
INFO    |   hw.display1.flag = 0
INFO    |   hw.display2.width = 0
INFO    |   hw.display2.height = 0
INFO    |   hw.display2.density = 0
INFO    |   hw.display2.xOffset = -1
INFO    |   hw.display2.yOffset = -1
INFO    |   hw.display2.flag = 0
INFO    |   hw.display3.width = 0
INFO    |   hw.display3.height = 0
INFO    |   hw.display3.density = 0
INFO    |   hw.display3.xOffset = -1
INFO    |   hw.display3.yOffset = -1
INFO    |   hw.display3.flag = 0
INFO    |   hw.gpu.enabled = true
INFO    |   hw.gpu.mode = host
INFO    |   hw.initialOrientation = Portrait
INFO    |   hw.camera.back = none
INFO    |   hw.camera.front = none
INFO    |   vm.heapSize = 512
INFO    |   hw.sensors.light = true
INFO    |   hw.sensors.pressure = true
INFO    |   hw.sensors.humidity = true
INFO    |   hw.sensors.proximity = true
INFO    |   hw.sensors.magnetic_field = true
INFO    |   hw.sensors.magnetic_field_uncalibrated = true
INFO    |   hw.sensors.gyroscope_uncalibrated = true
INFO    |   hw.sensors.orientation = true
INFO    |   hw.sensors.temperature = true
INFO    |   hw.sensors.rgbclight = false
INFO    |   hw.sensor.hinge = false
INFO    |   hw.sensor.hinge.count = 0
INFO    |   hw.sensor.hinge.type = 0
INFO    |   hw.sensor.hinge.sub_type = 0
INFO    |   hw.sensor.hinge.fold_to_displayRegion.0.1_at_posture = 1
INFO    |   hw.sensor.roll = false
INFO    |   hw.sensor.roll.count = 0
INFO    |   hw.sensor.roll.resize_to_displayRegion.0.1_at_posture = 6
INFO    |   hw.sensor.roll.resize_to_displayRegion.0.2_at_posture = 6
INFO    |   hw.sensor.roll.resize_to_displayRegion.0.3_at_posture = 6
INFO    |   hw.sensors.heart_rate = false
INFO    |   hw.sensors.wrist_tilt = false
INFO    |   hw.useext4 = true
INFO    |   hw.arc = false
INFO    |   hw.arc.autologin = false
INFO    |   hw.device.name = pixel_xl
INFO    |   kernel.path = /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//kernel-ranchu
INFO    |   kernel.newDeviceNaming = yes
INFO    |   kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
INFO    |   disk.ramdisk.path = /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//ramdisk.img
INFO    |   disk.systemPartition.initPath = /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//system.img
INFO    |   disk.systemPartition.size = 4107m
INFO    |   disk.vendorPartition.initPath = /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//vendor.img
INFO    |   disk.vendorPartition.size = 800m
INFO    |   disk.dataPartition.path = /home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/userdata-qemu.img
INFO    |   disk.dataPartition.size = 6g
INFO    |   disk.encryptionKeyPartition.path = /home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/encryptionkey.img
INFO    |   PlayStore.enabled = false
INFO    |   avd.name = Pixel_XL_API_31
INFO    |   avd.id = Pixel_XL_API_31
INFO    |   fastboot.forceColdBoot = false
INFO    |   android.sdk.root = /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk
INFO    |   android.avd.home = /home/dejfcold/.android/avd
INFO    | .
INFO    | QEMU options list:
INFO    |    argv[00] = "/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64"
INFO    |    argv[01] = "-dns-server"
INFO    |    argv[02] = "127.0.0.53"
INFO    |    argv[03] = "-mem-path"
INFO    |    argv[04] = "/home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img"
INFO    |    argv[05] = "-mem-file-shared"
INFO    |    argv[06] = "-serial"
INFO    |    argv[07] = "null"
INFO    |    argv[08] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[09] = "goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=/home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/data/misc/pstore/pstore.bin"
INFO    |    argv[10] = "-cpu"
INFO    |    argv[11] = "android64"
INFO    |    argv[12] = "-enable-kvm"
INFO    |    argv[13] = "-smp"
INFO    |    argv[14] = "cores=4"
INFO    |    argv[15] = "-m"
INFO    |    argv[16] = "2048"
INFO    |    argv[17] = "-lcd-density"
INFO    |    argv[18] = "560"
INFO    |    argv[19] = "-object"
INFO    |    argv[20] = "iothread,id=disk-iothread"
INFO    |    argv[21] = "-nodefaults"
INFO    |    argv[22] = "-kernel"
INFO    |    argv[23] = "/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//kernel-ranchu"
INFO    |    argv[24] = "-initrd"
INFO    |    argv[25] = "/home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/initrd"
INFO    |    argv[26] = "-drive"
INFO    |    argv[27] = "if=none,index=0,id=system,if=none,file=/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//system.img,read-only"
INFO    |    argv[28] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[29] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
INFO    |    argv[30] = "-drive"
INFO    |    argv[31] = "if=none,index=1,id=cache,if=none,file=/home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
INFO    |    argv[32] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[33] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
INFO    |    argv[34] = "-drive"
INFO    |    argv[35] = "if=none,index=2,id=userdata,if=none,file=/home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
INFO    |    argv[36] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[37] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
INFO    |    argv[38] = "-drive"
INFO    |    argv[39] = "if=none,index=3,id=encrypt,if=none,file=/home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/encryptionkey.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
INFO    |    argv[40] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[41] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=encrypt,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
INFO    |    argv[42] = "-drive"
INFO    |    argv[43] = "if=none,index=4,id=vendor,if=none,file=/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//vendor.img,read-only"
INFO    |    argv[44] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[45] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
INFO    |    argv[46] = "-drive"
INFO    |    argv[47] = "if=none,index=5,id=sdcard,if=none,file=/home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/sdcard.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
INFO    |    argv[48] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[49] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=sdcard,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
INFO    |    argv[50] = "-netdev"
INFO    |    argv[51] = "user,id=mynet"
INFO    |    argv[52] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[53] = "virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet"
INFO    |    argv[54] = "-chardev"
INFO    |    argv[55] = "null,id=forhvc0"
INFO    |    argv[56] = "-chardev"
INFO    |    argv[57] = "null,id=forhvc1"
INFO    |    argv[58] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[59] = "virtio-serial-pci,ioeventfd=off"
INFO    |    argv[60] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[61] = "virtconsole,chardev=forhvc0"
INFO    |    argv[62] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[63] = "virtconsole,chardev=forhvc1"
INFO    |    argv[64] = "-chardev"
INFO    |    argv[65] = "rootcanal,id=rootcanal"
INFO    |    argv[66] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[67] = "virtserialport,chardev=rootcanal,name=bluetooth"
INFO    |    argv[68] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[69] = "virtio-serial,ioeventfd=off"
INFO    |    argv[70] = "-chardev"
INFO    |    argv[71] = "socket,port=43375,host=::1,nowait,nodelay,ipv6,id=modem"
INFO    |    argv[72] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[73] = "virtserialport,chardev=modem,name=modem"
INFO    |    argv[74] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[75] = "virtio-rng-pci"
INFO    |    argv[76] = "-show-cursor"
INFO    |    argv[77] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[78] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_1"
INFO    |    argv[79] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[80] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_2"
INFO    |    argv[81] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[82] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_3"
INFO    |    argv[83] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[84] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_4"
INFO    |    argv[85] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[86] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_5"
INFO    |    argv[87] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[88] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_6"
INFO    |    argv[89] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[90] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_7"
INFO    |    argv[91] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[92] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_8"
INFO    |    argv[93] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[94] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_9"
INFO    |    argv[95] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[96] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_10"
INFO    |    argv[97] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[98] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_11"
INFO    |    argv[99] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[100] = "virtio-keyboard-pci"
INFO    |    argv[101] = "-netdev"
INFO    |    argv[102] = "user,id=virtio-wifi,dhcpstart=10.0.2.16"
INFO    |    argv[103] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[104] = "virtio-wifi-pci,netdev=virtio-wifi"
INFO    |    argv[105] = "-device"
INFO    |    argv[106] = "virtio-vsock-pci,guest-cid=77"
INFO    |    argv[107] = "-L"
INFO    |    argv[108] = "/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib/pc-bios"
INFO    |    argv[109] = "-soundhw"
INFO    |    argv[110] = "hda"
INFO    |    argv[111] = "-vga"
INFO    |    argv[112] = "none"
INFO    |    argv[113] = "-append"
INFO    |    argv[114] = "no_timer_check clocksource=pit console=0 cma=314M@0-4G loop.max_part=7 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000 printk.devkmsg=on bootconfig"
INFO    |    argv[115] = "-android-hw"
INFO    |    argv[116] = "/home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
INFO    | Concatenated QEMU options: /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -dns-server 127.0.0.53 -mem-path /home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img -mem-file-shared -serial null -device goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=/home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/data/misc/pstore/pstore.bin -cpu android64 -enable-kvm -smp cores=4 -m 2048 -lcd-density 560 -object iothread,id=disk-iothread -nodefaults -kernel /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//kernel-ranchu -initrd /home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/initrd -drive if=none,index=0,id=system,if=none,file=/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//system.img,read-only -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,if=none,file=/home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=2,id=userdata,if=none,file=/home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=3,id=encrypt,if=none,file=/home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/encryptionkey.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=encrypt,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=4,id=vendor,if=none,file=/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-31/google_apis/x86_64//vendor.img,read-only -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=5,id=sdcard,if=none,file=/home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/sdcard.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=sdcard,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -netdev user,id=mynet -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet -chardev null,id=forhvc0 -chardev null,id=forhvc1 -device virtio-serial-pci,ioeventfd=off -device virtconsole,chardev=forhvc0 -device virtconsole,chardev=forhvc1 -chardev rootcanal,id=rootcanal -device virtserialport,chardev=rootcanal,name=bluetooth -device virtio-serial,ioeventfd=off -chardev socket,port=43375,host=::1,nowait,nodelay,ipv6,id=modem -device virtserialport,chardev=modem,name=modem -device virtio-rng-pci -show-cursor -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_1 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_2 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_3 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_4 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_5 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_6 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_7 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_8 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_9 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_10 -device virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_11 -device virtio-keyboard-pci -netdev user,id=virtio-wifi,dhcpstart=10.0.2.16 -device virtio-wifi-pci,netdev=virtio-wifi -device virtio-vsock-pci,guest-cid=77 -L /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib/pc-bios -soundhw hda -vga none -append 'no_timer_check clocksource=pit console=0 cma=314M@0-4G loop.max_part=7 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000 printk.devkmsg=on bootconfig' -android-hw /home/dejfcold/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_31.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
VERBOSE | Starting hostapd main loop.
VERBOSE | Android qemu version 31.2.9.0 (build_id 8316981) (CL:N/A)
VERBOSE | Starting QEMU main loop
VERBOSE | registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '196608'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'none'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.adb.secure' = '1'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '512m'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '560'
INFO    | Rootcanal has  been activated.
VERBOSE | control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-dpad: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-trackball: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-camera: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-keyboard: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-tabletmode: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-touch: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-multitouch: false
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'net.wifi_mac_prefix' = '5554'
VERBOSE | Not using any http proxy
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.timezone' = 'Europe/Bratislava'
VERBOSE | android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_301578.ini
VERBOSE | emulator_window_fb_rotate
VERBOSE | config multidisplay with config.ini 0x0 0x0 0x0
VERBOSE | No acpi ini file provided, using default
VERBOSE |  no root specified: 
VERBOSE | Path:/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb protocol version: 41
VERBOSE | Found: 1 adb executables
VERBOSE | Adb: /home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '196608'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'none'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.adb.secure' = '1'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '512m'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '560'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'net.wifi_mac_prefix' = '5554'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.timezone' = 'Europe/Bratislava'
VERBOSE | Path:/home/dejfcold/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb protocol version: 41
VERBOSE | _hwFingerprint_connect: connect finger print listen is called
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Wayland with Gnome. To verify you are using Wayland in Gnome you can go to "Settings" > "About" under "Windowing system" it will say "Wayland".

I had the same problem (on Fedora 36) and switching to XOrg fixed the issue for me. When logging in (with GDM) after you have entered (or selected) your username you can press on the cog in the lower right corner and select "Gnome on XOrg".

Comment: Thank you very much kind stranger. You solved my problem